# How to make business card with fpdf or tcpdf or others? When i have a jpg background and text overlap requires?

Tags: php, zend-framework, fpdf, tcpdf, pdflib

I have a jpg image for the business card layout with dimensions: 9,8 cm/5,9 cm. I have to put it as background layout and on top of this layout i have to print name/address/telephone number email etc. And print it/save it as pdf for later use.

But problem is i cant make it work with FPDF or TCPDF. Any idea how can i prepare this? with FPDF or TCPDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using TCPDF you can position elements absolutely as it were, so you could do something like

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'mm', 'A4'); //Or whatever your required settings are

//Basic setup
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Image('src', x, y); //Where x and y are the offset (probably 0, 0)
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(w, h, x, y, 'html') //Again where x and y are offset

$pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D'); //To force download
```

The TCPDF online documentation isn't great, but the examples help a lot http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Answer (score 2):

You specifically asked about creating a business card sized document, so you should use:

```
//Sets document size to a 5.9cm x 9.8cm landscape oriented page    
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'mm', array(59,98));
```

The documentation gives a list of pre-defined page sizes here: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a087d4df77e60b7054e97804069ed32c5

Comment: Also i have some problem like the printer is support width 98 but height 91 minimum. The business card is getting jammed when i insert them in landscape way to the rare trey. But if i put the business card as P mode then the 91 mm as height is accepted by the printer. But in that case it does not print rotate 90 degree or -90 degree. And all shapes gets broken.

Answer (score 0):

The example n. 51 at http://www.tcpdf.org shows how to create a full page background.
Then, for the page format, check the source code documentation of the getPageSizeFromFormat() method (more than 300 page formats are already defined, including business cards).

Answer (score 0):

To set the background on fpdf you have to call Image() as the first thing when setting up the Header() function in your class.

The way I normally do it is by extending Extend FPDF in my own class, i.e.:

require('path/to/fpdf.php);

    class SomeClassName extends FPDF {
        // add your instance variables if needed 
        ....
        function Header(){
            //now call Image()
            $this->Image(); //set up your background here 
            ...
         }
    }

If you look at faqs in the fpdf.org site you will see (vague) instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library which implements **FPDF** called **FPDI**. To create custom paper sizes, like business cards, which typically use **CR80** with dimensions of **54mm x 86mm**, you can directly add this size into the class constructor of **fpdf.php** at **stdPageSizes** as this: **'cr80'=>array(152.82,243.38)**. This entry already exists so just add this custom one. Your complete definition will be something like this:

```
$this->StdPageSizes = array('a3'=>array(841.89,1190.55), 'a4'=>array(595.28,841.89), 'a5'=>array(420.94,595.28), 'letter'=>array(612,792), 'legal'=>array(612,1008), 'cr80'=>array(152.82,243.38));
```

Your calls, if using FPDI, will now be something like this:

```
$pdf = new Fpdi();
$pdf->AddPage('L','cr80');   //note our custom name
```

Note that even though the right size of CR80 is 54x86mm, it seems that the right settings require that these values be multiplied by 2.83 - tested. I hope this helps in code shortenings and quick reuse.